# Is ${Y(t) : t ≥ 0}$ second order stationary?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stationary-processes

Let $ {X(t) : t ≥ 0} $ be a stochastic process that satisfies the following conditions:

$-{X(t) : t ∈ T} ∈ M2$$

-It has independent increments

-It has stationary increments

Define a new stochastic process ${Y (t) : t ≥ 0}$ as:

$$Y (t) = X(t + 5) − X(t + 2)$$

Is ${Y(t) : t ≥ 0}$ second order stationary?

I have really tried but I get confused in the properties, I appreciate the help

Comment: Is the dollar after the $M2$ a typo ?

Comment: And why the hypothesis of stationary increments? Isn't it a redundant hypothesis?  An M2 process with the joints of two variables shift invariant should have also increments automatically stationary no?

Answer (score 0):

I think I had misunderstood the question, the OP wants to show that $Y$ is weakly stationary, not that $Y$ is M2 stationary.

So we have a starting process which is M2, that is the joint distributions up to two variables are shift invariant, i.e. $X(t) \sim X(t+\tau)$ and $(X(t),X(t')) \sim (X(t+\tau),X(t'+\tau))$.

We want to know that the process $Y(t)=X(t+5)-X(t+2)$ is second order stationary, meaning that the mean, variance and covariance are shift invariant (also called weakly stationary), so:

1- $E[Y(t)]=E[X(t+5)-X(t+2)]=E[X(t+5)]-E[X(t+2)]=0$

2- $E[Y(t)Y(t')]=E[(X(t+5)-X(t+2))(X(t'+5)-X(t'+2))]=$

$=E[X(t+5)X(t'+5)]-E[X(t+5)X(t'+2)]-E[X(t+2)X(t'+5)]+E[X(t+2)X(t'+2)]=$

Now since the process is $M2$ stationary all joint distributions of two variables (and in particular the means) are invariant after the transformation:

$t \rightarrow t+\tau$, $t' \rightarrow t'+\tau$

showing that:

$E[Y(t)Y(t')]=E[Y(t+\tau)Y(t'+\tau)]$

Therefore since the mean of the process is zero we have shown that the covariances are stationary.

**Comment:** I was not able to show that the process $Y(t)$ is $M2$ (i.e. to show that the distribution of $(Y(t),Y(t'))$ is shift invariant, but probably this is not a part of the question ? I suspect it is false but maybe somebody can also comment on this ?

Comment: Can the OP comment on whether I used the correct definitions for his question ?